# Does service broker use the same session for stored procedure exec / risk of temporary table collisions?

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables, service-broker

When using a # temporary table in a stored procedure activated by a service broker queue, if ~ simultaneous messages activate the stored procedure multiple times, will the "readers" of the queue use the same session, and, de facto, the same temporary tables ?

ref : [this post that sounds like each activation will have its own session.. but am I understanding it wrong ?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13698/what-is-the-difference-between-a-connection-and-a-session/13700#13700)
ref 2 : [That msdn doc that left me puzzled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171585.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each reader thread, up to `MAX_QUEUE_READERS`, will have its own session. This must be true, otherwise they could not execute in parallel. Within a session (thread), the stored procedure may be called repeatedly. So two *simultaneous* instances of the stored proc cannot collide on accessing `#temp` table, but the `#temp` table may be already populated from a previous execution on the same session.

Comment: Thanks a lot to clarify that for me ;) I was using contrived methods to encapsulate things to use table variables -to not use any alters/inserts, etc.- instead of temp tables and that was soooo painful ^^

Comment: But since you cannot create the #temp table *outside* the stored proc, since you have no access to the session, then you can only create the #temp table inside the proc. such #temp tables are supposed to be dropped automatically when the stored procedure terminates.

Comment: Yes absolutely, I create them and drop them inside the proc.